# Can you use an .iso Image to boot a Win XP-Pro SP3 "Formatted HDD", via CD-DVD-RW?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, iso-image

I have a Compaq (HP) 6710-b Laptop and the HDD became un-usable. All backups and boot disks have mysteriously vanished over the years, (kid's I'm thinkin) So my backup HDD is a fully formatted 160GB. And as i am beginning to learn .iso files like to have the OS up and running. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if I understand, you want to boot your computer on the ISO file ? If so, you'll have to burn this file to a CD/DVD or to create a bootable USB stick based on this ISO.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I want to use an Image file (.iso) to put the complete OS (Win XP-Pro/SP3) back onto a completely blank 160gb HDD, on a Compaq 6710b.

Answer (score 0):

`.iso files like to have the OS up and running` that is called live-cd, due to some limitation of Windows you can't running a full OS at live mode (possible Windows PE only) or you may try [ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/index_roadshow)

Comment: Oops, try again. Yes i fooled with one earlier on, but my drive is only a 1gb in size, my 4gb grew legs. Anyways good call going to give it a go again as i find i can get the files needed in under a gig, not to mention a little more educated about the whole process with using .iso's and cd burners etc, etc. Thanks for the input @Bilo and will post on the results. Although i"m still wondering about the  formatting of pendrive. 64bit or 32bit, do i need to use a 32bit machine and the cd/dvd in it. Or can you use a 64bit machine formatted pendrive and have it read properly on a 32bit machine?